# Why am I getting 'vector subscript out of range'?

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm trying to do the simplest thing, but I'm getting a 'vector subscript out of range' error! I don't understand why though because I check to make sure that doesn't happen. The only function it occurs with is the `addTexture` one.

## TextureBank.h

```
#pragma once
#include "Disposable.h"
#include "Texture.h"
#include <vector>

class TextureBank: public Disposable
{
public:
    TextureBank();
    ~TextureBank();

    virtual void dispose();

    void addTexture(int location, Texture *tex);
    Texture *getTexture(int location);
private:
    std::vector<Texture*> textures;
};
```

## TextureBank.cpp

```
#include "TextureBank.h"


TextureBank::TextureBank()
{
}

void TextureBank::dispose() {
    for each (Texture* tex in textures)
    {
        if (tex != nullptr) {
            tex->dispose();
        }
    }
}

void TextureBank::addTexture(int location, Texture *tex) {
    if (location > textures.size() - 1) {
        textures.resize(location + 1, nullptr);
    }
    textures[location] = tex;
}

Texture *TextureBank::getTexture(int location) {
    return textures[location];
}

TextureBank::~TextureBank()
{
    for each (Texture* tex in textures)
    {
        if (tex != nullptr) {
            delete tex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: vector subscript out of range means "you asked for an element from the vector, but the vector is not of that size". e.g. `vector<int> vec; vec.push_back(42); vec[1] // oops, 42 is vec[0]`

Comment: (Also, why the `Disposeable` concept? That's what destructors are for!)

Comment: @BillyONeal So I can rid of opengl resources before deleting everything else

Comment: @BillyONeal But why isn't the vector of that size, I mean I check in the code if it is, and if not, then resize until it is. Why doesnt that work?

Comment: `location > textures.size() - 1` I'm surprised your compiler doesn't give you a signed/unsigned mismatch warning there.

Comment: @ChrisDrew No, because I specifically set it to 0, that's why I'm so confused :(

Comment: @JonathanPotter Oh! I didn't know it worked like that. I did `if (location + 1 > textures.size())` and it worked. (Just rebalanced the inequality) I didn't realize `vector::size()` returned an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The culprit is most likely this statement:

```
if (location > textures.size() - 1) {
```

`textures.size()` will be an unsigned integral type, and `location` is an `int`. Prior to the greater than comparison, [usual arithmetic conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t4w2bkb.aspx) will be applied, which means `location` will be converted to the same unsigned integral type.

If `textures` is empty and `location` is zero, `textures.size() - 1` will result in the maximum value for that unsigned type, and the comparison will yield `false`. `textures` will not be resized, and you'll try to access the zeroth element of an empty `vector`, resulting in the exception.

You can easily fix the condition by modifying it to

```
if (location >= textures.size()) {
```

Also consider making `location` an unsigned type if cannot be negative; and turn your compiler's warning level up and pay attention to the warnings!

---

You should also consider making some other changes:

- `for each (Texture* tex in textures)` is some non-standard compiler extension. You should replace this with a range based `for` if possible - `for(auto tex : textures)`
- Instead of storing raw owning pointers in `textures`, consider changing the type to `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Texture>>`. Then you won't have to explicitly `delete` each texture in the destructor.
- If you cannot use `unique_ptr`, make sure your class follows the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).
- Instead of using `Dispose()` functions and such, you'd be better off creating small RAII wrappers to handle the OpenGL types that require memory management.

Comment: Yep! Thanks and we also solved it in the comments. Instead of doing `location >= textures.size()` I did `location + 1 > textures.size()` which also works (so no negatives) :)

Comment: @name Yeah, that works too, but I'd personally rather use `>=` than dealing with an offset.